# TSQL update value with subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, compare

I have 2 tables and want to compare them and modify `tableA` (`set NameMod = 1`) if it has different rows.

To compare tables I use:

```
 select Id, Name from tableB
 except
 select Id, Name from tableA
```

And then I want to modify `tableA`:

```
 update tableA Set NameMod = 1
 where exists (
  select Id, Name from tableB
  except
  select Id, Name from tableA
  )
```

But I can only use `EXISTS` before the sub-query and in this case it updates all elements in table not different rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try this:

```
MERGE TableA AS [Target]
USING TableB AS [Source]
    ON [Target].[ID] = [Source].[ID]
    AND [Target].[Name ] = [Source].[Name]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN UPDATE SET NameMod = 1;
```

It is using the [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) clause.

If you do not like the clause, you can use `CTE` like this:

```
;WITH IdsForUpdate ([id]) AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Id
    FROM
    (
        select Id, Name from tableB
          except
          select Id, Name from tableA
    ) DS([id], [name])
)
 update tableA 
 Set NameMod = 1
 FROM tableA A
 INNER JOIN IdsForUpdate B
    ON A.[id] =  B.[id];
```